# How to change Data in GridView over 2 Tables?

Tags: asp.net

I bound a List of a LINQ-Table to my gridview.

Now I will have a foraign key information in my gridview:

- Table User : UserID, username ....
- Table Adresses: AdressID, UserID, Adress ...
- 1 User has x adresses

Now I bound normaly over

```
(from a in dc.adresses select a).ToList()
```

the LINQ-Information to my Gridview by an ObjectDataSource.

There is now shown the UserID in ID. How to show there my Username insted?

ASP.Net, C#.Net 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    (from a in dc.adresses join u in dc.user on a equals u.UserID 
select new { UserID = a.UserID, u.UserName}).ToList()
```

Comment: I know how to do it, that in the List is the USername given, but how I change the GridView to display this?

Comment: if username is in list, then it will appear as UserID appears. How you bound the UserID to grid? please show code.